# Popup document content on a view?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I currently have a older Domino site.   It has a view that I have implemented clueTip to display content of the document as I hover over the link.  The popup will close when the mouse is moved off of the link.

I would like to convert the site to xPages and eliminate jQuery and clueTip and go with all native xPages or dojo components but have similar behavior with my existing site.

One thought was to use the extension library dialog box but it has the title bar and I would rather not have the title bar.

Any idea how I can display contents from a notes document in a popup on my xpage view?

P.S.  While the view is an old DOmino web view, the popup is a recent additon to the view and it is actually an xpage.  I feed the clueTip control the URL of the xpage document via the rel parameter in the anchor tag and the xpage is displayed in a popup.   If I could leverage that same xpage url that would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Tooltip `xe:tooltip` control from Extension Library tab to show a document in a popup.

You can find a good example in [XPages Extension Library Demo](http://extlib.openntf.org/) in Core_Tooltip.xsp.

[image]

Comment: There's also Tooltip Dialog